# Using Bayes theorem what is the probability of dropping the call after 50sec given call was not dropped during first 20 sec.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I have probabilities of dropping a call based on the duration of time customer has waited for before dropping.

Probability of dropping during  0-20sec: 0.23

Probability of dropping during 20-40sec: 0.11

Probability of dropping during 40-50sec: 0.04

Probability of dropping during 50-60sec: 0.61

Now I want to know the probability of dropping the call during 50-60sec when it is known that the call has not been dropped during 0-20sec.

How can we solve it using Bayes theorem ?

Comment: Do you really need Bayes theorem? How about just using the formula for conditional probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

$$\frac{0.61}{1-0.23}=\frac{61}{77}$$

**This simple operation is exactly Bayes Theorem,** or Conditional Probability formula...it's the same

Set:

> $A$ as the event:  "dropping during 50-60sec"
>
> $B$ the complement of the event "dropping during 0-20"

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A)}{P(B)}$$

being $A \subset B$

Comment: Can please you relate it to Bayes theorem and provide some explanation ?

Comment: @Abhisheksoni : done in the edit of my answer. Since you're new here, I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future